# Confusion in how to find number of onto functions if two sets are given

Tags: combinatorics, functions, combinations

In the book it is given if **A** and **B** are two finite sets containing $m$ and $n$ elements, respectively, then the number of onto functions from **A** to **B** will be if

$n \leq m$

$$\sum_{r=1}^n (-1)^{(n-r)} {n \choose r}(r)^m $$

well I can't understand it and I am aware with combinations.

Comment: Any attempt towards the solution?

Comment: See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle and search for Info functions.

Comment: Its inclusion-exclusion.

Comment: Of course "info functions" should read as "onto functions".